# Are there any easy to use distributed relational databases?

Tags: database, relational-database, distributed

I've been talking with one of my friends about distributed relational databases, using the defintion:

1. Supports everything a relational database does (SQL, ACID)
2. Distributed (multiple servers)
3. Automatic (or automatic-ish) -- Install the program on multiple servers, give them whatever information they need to communicate (IP addresses), and then they figure out how to distribute things automatically

(3) is the part that doesn't seem to be done anywhere. You can do sharding, but then you need extra code in your application to figure out which server to talk to. What I'm looking for is something like Memcached, but as a relational database (Memcached is key-value), and ACID-compliant (Memcached is in-memory only, and I doesn't have anything like transactions).

Obviously something like this would be incredibly complicated to do well, but it surprises me that I can't see to find any examples of it being done.

Comment: What you want to achieve by having it distributed ?
What's your supposed read:write ratio ?
Do you really need transactions ? I don't thing there is a silver bullet. You have to make your priorities clear.

Comment: My goal is to see if it's been done and how. How something like this would perform is part of what interests us.

Answer (score 3):

[Teradata](http://www.teradata.com/products-and-services/database/teradata-13/) provides this but it is sold as an appliance. They have an automatically sharded ACID and SQL compliant RDBMS but you have to buy the nodes from them.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I represent NimbusDB.

[NuoDB](http://nuodb.com/) (previously NimbusDB) does exactly this. It's hard to do if you start with traditional database architectures, but you get it for free if you start with a modern distributed architecture.

Comment: This seems to be a work in progress though right?

Comment: It's worth mentioning another database you talked about in your blog: VoltDB. It obviously doesn't meet all the requirements in my question (transactions don't work how you'd expect), but it's fairly close.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is... What kind of replication do you need. There are many kinds of solutions:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Part of the replication is built into postgres 9.0 and up, btw.